# undefined method `salt='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I am trying to add a password thing to my website. But when I sign up an account, the page that shows up after I press the sign up button is an error page showing:

undefined method `salt=' for #<User:0x37f8168>
app/models/user.rb:34:in`encrypt_password'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `create'

In my user.rb I have:

```
def encrypt_password
      self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
      self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
    end

    def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
    end
```

In users_controller.rb I have

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to PennTwit"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

The error is with the lines:

```
if @user.save

self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
```

I tried changing self.salt to @salt but it gave me another error saying salt in

> secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}") is
>   not found.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a plugin? (Is this restful_authentication?)

Comment: I don't think I am using a plugin. What's a restful_authentication?

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication (kind of old news these days but your code looks remarkably similar, right down to he double dash between salt/password). See your vendor/plugins directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that `salt` is `an undefined method` :)

I think that you haven't got `salt` field in your database `users` table.

Show your user table structure (or at least migration)

Comment: I did rails generate migration add_salt_to_users salt:string

This should add it to the db doesn't it? But I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You should make `salt` attribute as `attr_accessor` in your model like

`attr_accessor :salt`

Comment: I tried that and I got a new error:

undefined method `encrypted_password='

which is weird because salt is in this method and it didn't detect this error before.

Comment: do the same with encrypted_password

Comment: attr_accessor creates automatically get, set and salt= methods.

Answer (score 0):

in the gem file add Bcrypt, its responsible for encryption/decreption

gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"

now edit your method

```
def encrypt_password 

    if password.present? 
       self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt 
       self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)  
    end
```